# Get column names as comma-separated list for the column where value greater than 0 in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have a table with columns as below

| Name | List | Apple | Orange | Mango | Banana | Cherry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

`Name` contains the names of the vendors.

`Apple  Orange  Mango   Banana  Cherry` contains the QTY like 1,10,15.....

This is what I need

`List` name of fruits where the value is greater than 0 as [Apple, Orange]

[image]

Do let me know if things are not clear.

Thank you in advance for answering the question

I tried `VLookup` but not sure if I am making any mistake

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/C3:AC3,C$2:AC$2)
```

In this, I need to set it for each Column I need a Dynamic Column

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CONCATENATE(IF(C3>0,$C$2 & ",",""),IF(D3>0,$D$2& 
",",""),IF(E3>0,$E$2& ",",""),IF(F3>0,$F$2& 
",",""),IF(G3>0,$G$2,","))),",",", ")
```

I am using the latest version of Excel on the web

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($C$1:$G$1,C2:G2<>""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using `TEXTJOIN()` with `IF()` --> Works with `Excel 2019+` onwards.

[image]

---

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(C2:G2<>"",$C$1:$G$1,""))
```

---

Or Use Single dynamic array formula to spill --> Works with `MS365`.

```
=BYROW(C2:G3,LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(x<>"",$C$1:$G$1,""))))
```

---

**Note:** `Excel 2019` Users needs to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode which is only applicable to first formula.

---

Answer (score 0):

With the traditional excel functions has to use as many additional column as fruits named Help1 to Help5 formula in W22 and drag to right.

`=V22&IF(Q22<>"",Q$21&",","")`

Formula in P22 and drag down

`=LEFT(AA22,LEN(AA22)-1)`   AA22 is the last column (Help5)

[image]